# issue in DDMenuController menuViewController like facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

My First Question

DDMenuController(facebook split menu) Must be on RootviewController? it can not be on other viewController which we push on rootViewCotroller?

if answer is no then

Second Question

i am trying to make split viewController like facebook for that i am using this sample

https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController

now what i want to do is i dont want set DDMenuControl as rootviewcontroller in appdelegate in my rootcontrollers there are view buttons which push my all other ViewController

so what i want is from my rootViewController' Buttons i push another controller and then that view should get pushed and same time there should be DDMenuController too

so what will happen is on navigation bar there wont be back button there will be splitting screen button like facebook and from there i can go to another view controller

now let me tell you what i have achieved so far my rootViewController is getting displayed and then from there i push my other ViewController and on navigation bar splitting button is also getting displayed but its not working let me should you code to make this all clear

this is how i set my rootViewContoller in app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary 

    *)launchOptions
    {

        FirstPadViewController *mainController = [[FirstPadViewController alloc] init];
        navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainController];



        self.window.rootViewController = navController;

        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

so it get displayed with some buttons from where i can push my other viewController

this is how i push my other ViewController

```
- (IBAction)goToCamera:(id)sender {

    AROverlayPadViewController *svController = [[AROverlayPadViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svController animated:YES];

    [svController release];
    svController = nil;
}
```

so AROverlayPadViewController is getting pushed

and in AROverlayPadViewController's viewWillAppear this is what i do for achieving splitting screen like facebook

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{


        DDMenuController *rootController = [[DDMenuController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];


        LeftController *leftController = [[LeftController alloc] init];
        rootController.leftViewController = leftController;
    }
```

splitting button is getting displayed but when i press it is not working

now i really dont have any clue what to do any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: did you find a way to include the DDMenuController for all your controllers?

Comment: Actually I figured it out myself. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first question: actually it's a yes. This is how you do it, in the method that sends you to your `nextScreen`:

```
-(void) goToAnotherController {
    OtherViewController *nextScreen = [OtherViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nextScreen];
    DDMenuController *menuController = (DDMenuController*)((AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).menuController;
    [menuController setRootController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: hello Eddy, I am facing one issue by using DDMenucontroller when i swipe right side a view a white space is occurring when my finger is on screen drag the view to right i can see the white space and i move out my finger from touch it comes to original . how to stop it.Please give suggestion.

Comment: @Romance I'm not sure what are you asking. Did you set the 'rightViewController' into the 'menuController'? Like this: 'self.menuController.rightViewController = self.sideMenu;' where sideMenu is a UIViewController. Also take a look at the '#define' section at the top of DDMenuController.m. There are several constants that may help you there.